# Is my if / else syntax correct? also Inputting the same quantity as the stocks it says not enough stock

Tags: php

When inputting higher order than the stocks it works but if I add an = before the < sign , it says parse and syntax error .

```
<?php
    include('session.php');
    if(isset($_POST['cart'])){
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        $qty=$_POST['qty'];

        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from cart where productid='$id' and userid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){
            echo "Product already on your cart!";
        }
            else if (mysqli_num_rows($query) < $qty){
            echo "Not enough stocks!";
        }
        else{
            mysqli_query($conn,"insert into cart (userid, productid, qty) values ('".$_SESSION['id']."', '$id', '$qty')");
        }
    }

?>
```

Thank you!

Comment: tried it but it says 
parse error , syntax error , unexpected '$lt,' at the line of my query

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: try <= not =< the second is wrong

Comment: marinus , tried still says not enough stock , even though the input is the same as the quantity

Comment: Your if-logic is wrong. The first if-statement (after the query) will always be executed if you get any rows back. I also don't get when you want the last else to be executed.

Comment: Magnus Eriksson , should I try , else if? , sorry Im not that good in programming

Comment: I don't know how  you should do it since I don't get what you're trying to accomplish. Can you edit your question to include when each if/else should be executed? I mean, the first takes anything that's more than zero, the second takes anything that's less than `$qty`, (which means that it _always_ will be executed when the first fails).